# Какой элемент WinForms использовать, для своебразной системы постов?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Изучаю Entity Framework, и в качестве примера делаю простую Постинг-систему.

В базе данных (сформированных по model-first), есть таблица Post, в которой, по умолчанию есть ключевое поле ID, ну и некоторая информация.

На главной форме я бы хотел выводить некоторые данные записи, т.е. Посты, отсортированные в обратном порядке (т.е. самый верхний пост - самый последний добавленный). Но как в этих элементах хранить идентификатор поста (в данном случае id), я не знаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поясню картинкой выше.

Как мне организовать такой контейнер, в котором собственно будут необходимые мне записи, а так же, как можно хранить данные об этих записях (чтобы например, по клике на запись, открылся пост с необходимым id, без различных проверок наполнения.

Спасибо!

Comment: [ListView](https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/4.12.php)?

Comment: @tym32167 не подскажешь, как образом мне хранить id. Я так предполагаю, что с помощью свойства Tag?

Comment: да (10 символов)

Comment: @tym32167 оформи как ответ. Помечу как решение)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [ListView](https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/4.12.php), данные для элемента listViewItem храните в свойстве Tag.

п.с. ну и классическое - если вы хотите делать красивый UI для настольного приложения под Windows, то вам лучше использовать WPF.

Comment: Пока мне не нужен красивый UI, для тренировки сойдет и WinForms)